# How can use CSS with X.PagedList.Mvc.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

[image]

I use X.PagedList.Mvc.Core for Table pagination. I need to use CSS or anything else for decoration beautiful than this.
And this below is code I use.

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.PagedListPager(permitPages, page => Url.Action("FindPermitNumber", "Permit", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithPageCountText)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated

- I already have a solution. I used PagedList.css from this link https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below to specifc the class attribute of the html element（I tried with the css of bootstrap）

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.PagedListPager(targetpagedlist, page => Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions(){ LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
    PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" }})
</div>
```

Now it looks like:

[image]